# XUL: How to edit popup's position

Tags: firefox, popup, firefox-addon, position, xul

i'm developing a simple Firefox Addon: a button with popup shown with a classical mouse over event.

Does someone know if is possible set the position of the popup ?

Ex: top left instead bottom right

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/popup.position)?

Also take a look at [positioning popups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Positioning). It also has an example.

Comment: the second link you post to me is inaccessible for my mozilla developer account, is it correct?

Comment: "You do not have permissions to view this page"  ... damn! MDN doc center doesn't works for me :-( .

Comment: Oh, now it works for me ... ths solution to the problem? logout.

Comment: There was a bug with one of the MDC proxy servers; it's fixed now.